# Is it possible to compile an array of ts.SourceFiles?

Tags: typescript, compilation

So basically, what I have is this:
My program gets multiple file paths(string[]) as input. My program then makes a sourceFile object for each of those files. I use a recursive method to walk over the AST from those sourceFiles and make small changes. I need to use the compiler to make sure all files are still valid code.

I have found ts.createProgram(), but that takes an array of file paths. That would mean I'll have to write each file to disk to compile it. That seems very inefficient because my program does this multiple times.


So... can I use a function, similar like ts.CreateProgram(), but give it SourceFile objects instead of file paths?